# Can't Boot after up upgrade to 12.04

Tags: boot

I have as asus 1005pe which I tried to upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04. It seems to stop loading at user bootsplash and hangs forever. Unfortunately, the machine doesn't have a cd drive and won't start from a usb disk, so using a live image is not an option.

My only hope is that I can get into a terminal screen. Please help.

Comment: Can you enter the recovery mode from GRUB? Hold shift after first boot screen to display GRUB before booting Ubuntu if it's hidden.

Comment: yes, but recovery mode just leads to a command line

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment (my previous answer has been converted to a comment for some reason), but want to help, so I'm writing another answer.

If you can boot to command line, try opening the /var/log/syslog and see if there are any suspicious errors listed at the time of your last unsuccessful boot.

```
nano /var/log/syslog
```

You could also try to disable the automatic boot to desktop manager by editing your GRUB file

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change the "quiet splash" to "" and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

If you have lightdm installed, you may have to also do

```
sudo touch /etc/init/lightdm.override
```

to disable the LightDM autostart.

If you manage to boot to CLI without the recovery mode with these settings, run

```
startx
```

or (if you have gdm installed)

```
sudo service gdm start
```

or (if you have lightdm installed)

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

from your home folder and see if you can enter the X window system that way.